# I want to email users an encrypted file from a Django Backend Script on Ubuntu

Tags: django, encryption

I want to email users an encrypted file from a Django Backend Script (running through manage.py) on Ubuntu.  How can I encrypt the data so that it is unreadable by 3rd parties who might intercept or even just read the email and will require a password string that I can supply to the end user via another method (not email.)

What encryption scheme and application for Django/Ubuntu can I use so that a doctor could easily decrypt the data from their PC/MAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/django-email-extras/

Answer (score 2):

[PGP](http://www.pgp.com/) was invented for just this purpose.

EDIT: you might also consider the free (as in freedom), open-source project [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) which is the same standard, just free :)

Answer (score 2):

As Scott mentioned, you can use GPG to encrypt the data. See also the [Python bindings](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GnuPrivacyGuard) you can choose from to interface. To send email from Django (backend script or not), [read the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/).